# NoSuchMethodError when using Scala in R with rscala

Tags: r, scala

I'm having trouble using rscala package in R to call precompiled Scala code.

I have an Scala project running on version `2.11.12`. I build a fat jar with sbt-assembly and make it available to rscala through `rscala::scala("path-to-jar.jar")`

But whenever I try to run any function/method/whatever from the package, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at myPackage.myClass$.myMethod(myClass.scala:116)
    at $line6.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$.$anonfun$res0$1(<console>:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Server.$anonfun$invoke$3(Server.scala:305)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Server.wrap(Server.scala:47)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Server.invoke(Server.scala:305)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Server.run(Server.scala:400)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Main$.delayedEndpoint$org$ddahl$rscala$server$Main$1(Main.scala:105)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:11)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Main$.main(Main.scala:11)
    at org.ddahl.rscala.server.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$run$2(ScalaClassLoader.scala:106)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:132)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:106)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:98)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:132)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:35)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:34)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:73)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:92)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
Error in pop(details, transcompileInfo, envir) : Invocation error.
```

It does allow me to import its classes and objects, so it does seem to be in the classpath, but that's it.

My build.sbt includes `crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.7", "2.13.0-M5")` as required in the package.

Any thoughts? It seems like a scala version error, since running `rscala::scalaConfig()` shows me it is using `scalaFullVersion 2.12.8`, but I can't seem to choose a scala installation, so I can't really expect this to be the problem.

**EDIT:**

After Jasper-M's suggestion, I set environment variable `RSCALA_SCALA_MAJORVERSION=2.11` and reexecuted the config with `rscala::scalaConfig(download='scala')`. Now it returns `scalaMajorVersion` as `2.11`.

Now, when I create an instance of the scala bridge with `rscala::scala()`, it returns a message (not an error) saying:

```
cat: /release: No such file or directory
```

If I run `println()` it compiles with no issues. However, if I instantiate the scala bridge with a precompiled fat JAR of my own and do ANYTHING (like `println`), it returns the following error:

```
error: error while loading package, class file '$HOME/.rscala/scala/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/reflect/package.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation)
error: error while loading package, class file '$HOME/.rscala/scala/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/package.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation)
error: error while loading package, class file '$HOME/.rscala/scala/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/reflect/package.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation)
error: error while loading package, class file '$HOME/.rscala/scala/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/package.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation)
error: error while loading Predef, class file '$HOME/.rscala/scala/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/Predef.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation)
```

I'm really clueless here. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your dependencies in `build.sbt`?

Comment: Why are you targeting multiple Scala versions? The Spark installation only has one. It's either 2.11 (Spark <2.4) or 2.12 (Spark >=2.4). What do you mean by "required by the package"?

Comment: I'm not really, but the documentation suggests compiling with crossScalaVersion, probably because of this compatibility issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most definitely a Scala version error.

My best guess is that you have to set the environment variable `RSCALA_SCALA_MAJORVERSION=2.11` . E.g. by calling

```
Sys.setenv(RSCALA_SCALA_MAJORVERSION = "2.11")
```

and then run

```
rscala::scalaConfig(download = "scala")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and check if it works out. It does make sense.

Comment: I think we are close to make it work. `scalaConfig()` now returns `scalaMajorVersion` as `2.11`, which is great. I previously tried changing the file directly, but it didn't work. Setting the environment variable worked as you said. Now, however, when I try to create the bridge with `rscala::scala()`, it prints `cat: /release: No such file or directory` but still works. If I import my JAR, however, it breaks saying `error: error while loading package, class file '$HOME/.rscala/scala/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/reflect/package.class)' is broken` and other stuff. Ideas? I'll edit the post.

Comment: Fun fact. I tried to make an import and it returned a huge log with a fun remark at the end: `Error in rbyte(socketIn) : Scala seems to have died.`

Comment: @Edgar - I saw this same error today when trying to serialize an unsupported type (a `dttm` in my case). Switched it to a `String` with `format("%Y-%m-%DT%H-%m-%s")` and R happily sent it across.